# How do I set get variables in xslt?

Tags: php, xslt

I have the following problem while working in XSLT:

I want to make this link:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/product?title=example&number=09">Click me</a>
```

..in XSLT...

But I have no idea how. Right now it doesn't work because XSLT does not know the get symbols as ''? and '&'.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
& -> &amp;
" -> &quot;
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax

Comment: @_Kiril: The quote is one character that can be left unescaped in many cases in XML.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/product?title=example&amp;number=09">Click me</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{$vUrlPath}?title={$vTitle}&amp;number={$vNum}">Click me</a>
```

where The variables above have the necessary values.

**In XML the following characters must be always escaped, whenever they are not within a comment and are not used in their XML role** (denoting markup or entity reference):

`<`   -->  `&lt;`

`&`   --> `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the escape characters for special characters:

http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2215.html

Comment: Provide the actual escaped character and you get +1 :)